# Override node template depending on menu settings

Tags: 7, routes

How do I override the template of a node based on where it is in the menu?

For example, I create a node, and within the "Menu settings" I put it under some "parent item". I wish to use a specific template for nodes of a particular content type that fall under a particular parent item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by doing something like this in `theme_preprocess_page`

```
$link_path = "node/$node->nid";
$result = db_query('SELECT m.plid from {menu_links} m where m.link_path = :lpath', array(':lpath' => $link_path));
```

where plid, the parent menu id, is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible to achieve this in `hook_preprocess_node` by calling `menu_get_item`, checking whether it is the item you are looking for (checking the parent etc.) and then assigning the appropriate template like this: `$vars['template_file'] = 'your_template_file';`

Comment: I was unsuccessful in getting the menu parent item by simply calling `menu_get_item`.  There appeared to be no information gotten regarding menu items.  I've managed to figure it out however.  I'll post the answer.